# NotifyHeader.code results in segfault

Tags: c++, gtk, scintilla

I am trying to get the notification code from the sci-notify signal with scintilla, but I get a segfault. Here is my code:

```
void scinot(GtkWidget *s, SCNotification *notify, gpointer u)
{
    NotifyHeader nmhdr = notify->nmhdr;
    std::cout << nmhdr.code << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you're wondering why you have no comments or replies: it's impossible to say anything with the information you provide. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://sscce.org for generic advice. In practice you should (at the very least) provide code that shows what the `scinot()` function is used for -- e.g. if it's a signal handler you need to show how you connect it and what you connect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function signature is wrong. According to [the documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Notifications), it should be as follows:

`handler(GtkWidget *, gint, SCNotification *notification, gpointer userData)`

(you are missing the gint), making your function:

```
void scinot(GtkWidget *s, gint i,SCNotification *notify, gpointer u)
{
    NotifyHeader nmhdr = notify->nmhdr;
    std::cout << nmhdr.code << std::endl;
}
```